# Simple Calculator with multi digits

Tags: c#, winforms

when i was debugging the code the first numbers are doing the function correctly but when i was clicking the button "=" then the result is appearing at the text box and when i was using to click another button then the number is continuing from the result instead of clearing the field

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace CACalculator
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        double num1, num2, result;
        string op;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void btn9_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtnum.Text = txtnum.Text + btn9.Text;
        }

        private void btn8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtnum.Text = txtnum.Text+ btn8.Text;
        }

        private void btn7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtnum.Text = txtnum.Text+ btn7.Text;
        }

        private void btn6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtnum.Text = txtnum.Text+ btn6.Text;
        }

        private void btn5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtnum.Text = txtnum.Text+ btn5.Text;
        }

        private void btn4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtnum.Text = txtnum.Text+ btn4.Text;
        }

        private void btn3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtnum.Text = txtnum.Text+ btn3.Text;
        }

        private void btn2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtnum.Text = txtnum.Text+ btn2.Text;
        }

        private void btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtnum.Text = txtnum.Text+ btn1.Text;
        }

        private void btn0_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtnum.Text = txtnum.Text+ btn0.Text;
        }

        private void btnadd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            num1 = Convert.ToDouble(txtnum.Text);
            txtnum.Clear();
            op = btnadd.Text;
        }

        private void btnsub_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            num1 = Convert.ToDouble(txtnum.Text);
            txtnum.Clear();
            op = btnsub.Text;
        }

        private void btnmul_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            num1 = Convert.ToDouble(txtnum.Text);
            txtnum.Clear();
            op = btnmul.Text;
        }

        private void btndiv_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            num1 = Convert.ToDouble(txtnum.Text);
            txtnum.Clear();
            op = btndiv.Text;
        }

        private void btnquo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            num1 = Convert.ToDouble(txtnum.Text);
            txtnum.Clear();
            op = btnquo.Text;
        }

        private void btneql_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            num2 = Convert.ToDouble(txtnum.Text);
            switch (op)
            {
                case "+":
                    result = num1 + num2;
                    break;
                case "-":
                    result = num1 - num2;
                    break;
                case "*":
                    result = num1 * num2;
                    break;
                case "/":
                    result = num1 / num2;
                    break;
                case "%":
                    result = num1 % num2;
                    break;
            }
            txtnum.Text = result.ToString();
        }

        private void btnC_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtnum.Clear();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: how can I clear the result before entering another number. Once you run this and do any operation based on multiple digits use a double digit number and add with another double digit number and the result will be perfect but after the result, when we want to do another operation then the result is not clearing and the number what we have entered using the buttons will appear with continuation of the result

Comment: @user2738804 Shouldn't you use the Cancel button before you start another operation?

Comment: i was not using any cancel button before starting any other operation

Comment: Here the problem is when the result is generated and it is showing in the textbox and when we are entering another number for another operation the previous operation should be cleared and the text box should contain only the values what we have entered but here the values what we are entering in the text box are continuing from the result and the total number is the continutation of the result

Answer (score 1):

you have to clear Num1 and num2 aswel as the textbox, like so:

```
    private void btnC_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtnum.Clear();
        num1 = 0;    
        num2 = 0;   //clear all the numbers used in the calculator.
        result = 0; 
    }
```

otherwise you would clear the visual part but not the numbers that are behind it, which you are actually calculating with

Let me know if it helped.